# How to print content of a particular column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with 2 columns (Column 1=Words, Column 2=Clues). What I am trying to do is using pandas, randomly pick a work form 'Words' column, print it's Clue (from Column 2) and create a hangman game. 
Without the printing of clue part, my code below works just fine but what I am unable to accomplish is to print the corresponding clue for the randomly selected word. Any idea how to accomplish this??

```
import random
import pandas as ps
df1=ps.read_excel("C:/Python27/hangman_clues.xlsx")
#Randomly select a word from the 'Word' Column and convert to lowercase
word=random.choice(df1["Word"]).lower()
print "Welcome to Hangman"
print "Your Clue is"
#This is where I want to print the clue from 2nd column based on the 
randomly selected word which I am unable to accomplish. Tried 
df2=df1.set_index("Word",drop=False) but did not help much.

#below code works fine
guessedword=list('_'*len(word))
ctr=0
while ctr<len(word)+5:
    guessedchar=raw_input("Guess a char:")
    if guessedchar in word:
           getindex=[i.start() for i in re.finditer(guessedchar,word)]
           for index in getindex:
              guessedword[index]=guessedchar
              getindex=[]
              guessword="".join(guessedword)
           print str(guessedword)
           if word==guessword:
               print "you win"
               break


    ctr=ctr+1
```

Comment: Try to calculate number of rows in your excel file and then use random() function to generate a number between index 0 to n where n is number of rows as it will generate a number and you can then easily print the clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get a random index and use that for both the word and the corresponding clue.

```
index = random.randint(0, len(df1["Word"]))
word = df1["Word"][index]
print("Your clue is {}".format(df1["Clue"][index]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df1.sample(n=1)` which will return a DataFrame of one randomly selected row.

```
df_random_obs = df1.sample(n=1)
word = df_random_obs['Word']
clue = df_random_obs['Clue']
```